# Subtotal list values repeatedly until no duplicates remain

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of numbers in Python that may contain duplicates. I need to subtotal duplicate values to work with them, then later unpack the duplicates to arrive back at the original list and track what values were used in each subtotal. I'm running into problems where the first round of subtotaling results in new duplicates that must then be subtotaled. For example, the list [10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75] should be subtotaled as [40, 100, 75] because the subtotaling of the duplicate 10s results in new duplicate 20s that need to be subtotaled.

I've tried to use the following code which creates a dictionary of the duplicates and tracks the number of occurrences of each, but this doesn't work for this scenario.

```
import collections

def compress_dups(values):
    compressed_indices = []
    for val in set(values): 
        indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(values) if x == val]
        compressed_indices.append(indices)
    return(compressed_indices)  

compress_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
initial_list = [10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75]
compressed_list = []
g = compress_dups(initial_list)

print(initial_list)

for item in g:  
    compressed_list.append(len(item)*initial_list[min(item)])
    compress_dict[(len(item)*initial_list[min(item)])] = len(item)

print(sorted(compressed_list)) #this is the subtotaled list I'll work with

for k,v in reversed(compress_dict.items()):
    del compressed_list[compressed_list.index(k)]
    for x in xrange(v): 
        compressed_list.append(k/v)

print(sorted(compressed_list)) # this is the list after it's unpacked
```

Desired output:

```
[10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75]
[40, 75, 100]
[10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75]
```

Comment: why are you doing `min(item)`?

Comment: what output should be in case `[10, 20, 20, 10]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple function I made to do your task:

```
def count(lst):
    counter = []
    for e in sorted(lst):
        if e in counter:
            counter.remove(e)
            counter.append(e*2)
        else:
            counter.append(e)
    return counter # or return sorted(counter) if you want it to be sorted

initial_list = [10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75]
print(count(initial_list)) # prints [40, 100, 75] or [40, 75, 100] if its sorted

second_list = [5, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80]
print(count(second_list)) # prints [160]

third_list = [100, 50, 25, 25, 78]
print(count(third_list)) # prints [78, 200]
```

Explanation: this function creates a list, then iterate with `initial_list` to check if each value is already in the new list, if it is, remove it from the new list and append double of the value. If it's not, just add the value to the new list. Then it returns the new list.

Answer (score 0):

Lengthy but works,

```
def getNextLevel(a):
   b = []
   visited= []
   found = False
   for i in a: 
      if i not in visited:
         c = a.count(i)
         if c>1:
            found = True
         b.append(i*c)
         visited.append(i)
   return [b,found]

if __name__ =='__main__':
   a = [10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75]
   m = {}
   level = 1
   m[0] = a   
   while True:
      [b,f] = getNextLevel(a)
      if f:
         m[level] = b
         level +=1 
      else:
         break
      a = b

   #print     
   for i in range(level):
      print m[i]

   for i in range(level-2,-1,-1):
      print m[i]
```

Output,

```
[10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75]
[20, 20, 100, 75]
[40, 100, 75] 
[20, 20, 100, 75]
[10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this

```
def sum_dup(l):

for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i] == l[i+1]:
        l[i]+=l[i+1]
        l[i+1] = 0
        l.sort()
l = list(set(l))
l.remove(0)
return(l)

sum_dup(l)
```

returns

```
[40, 75, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to subtotal duplicate values to work with them, then later unpack the duplicates to arrive back at the original list and track what values were used in each subtotal.

In Python 3, it is possible to yield both results:

```
# Python 3
import collections as ct

def compress(initial, saved=None):
    """Yield a compressed list of summed repeated values and a Counter, else compress again."""
    c = ct.Counter(initial)
    if saved is None: saved = c                            # store starting Counter
    if len(initial) == len(set(initial)):
        yield initial
        yield saved
    else:
        compressed = sorted(k*v for k, v in c.items())
        yield from compress(compressed, saved=saved)

lst = [10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75]
tuple(compress(lst))
# ([40, 75, 100], Counter({10: 2, 20: 1, 50: 2, 75: 1}))
```

Here we yield both the compressed list and starting `Counter`.  Note: the term "`compress`" is not equivalent to `itertools.compress`.  We can now recover the original list by iterating the `Counter`:

```
clst, counter = tuple(compress(lst))
rlst = sorted(counter.elements())                          # sorted(k for k, v in counter.items() for _ in range(v))

print("Original list  :", lst)
print("Counter        :", counter)
print("Compressed list:", clst)
print("Recovered list :", rlst)
# Original list  : [10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75]
# Counter        : Counter({10: 2, 50: 2, 75: 1, 20: 1})
# Compressed list: [40, 75, 100]
# Recovered list : [10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75]
```

**Summary**: This example uses recursion, `yield from` and stores the starting Counter to recover the original list of multiple elements.  It works for multiple repeated items, not only duplicates.  Although 10x slower, the behavior parallel's @abccd's tests, differing if more repeated elements are encountered:

```
lst = [10, 10, 10, 20, 50, 50, 75]
tuple(compress(lst))[0]
# [20, 30, 75, 100]
```

Comment: This answer is helpful as well as it would also work for scenarios where there is more than just 1 duplicate of any number. Thanks!